# How to refresh a second window with a button click on the first

Tags: c#, wpf

How could I refresh a secodn window with a button click on the first window.

I am new to WPF and searched for long time but the answers I found didn't work. I am trying to write in a textbox on the main that it get posted on the second window. For so far I have that but I can only work with it when I use win1.show(). This gives a new pop-up screen with the typed text but not on the same page. So how could I get this instead of a pop up to refresh.

**Main window:**

```
    Title="MainWindow" Height="1050" Width="1680" ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip" Topmost="False" WindowState="Normal" Icon="./Resources/escapehaarlem_logo.ico" >
<Grid Background="Gray">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1593*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="80*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Button Content="Verstuur" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1330,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="334" Height="85" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Click="Verstuur_Button_Click"/>
    <Button Content="Verwijder" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1330,100,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="334" Height="85" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Click="Verwijder_Button_Click_1"/>
    <TextBox Name="Textbox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="1000" Margin="10,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1315"/>
</Grid>
```

**Second window:**

```
Title="MainWindow" Height="1050" Width="1680" ResizeMode="NoResize" Topmost="True" WindowState="Maximized" Icon="./Resources/escapehaarlem_logo.ico" >
<Grid Background="Black">
    <Label Name="lbl_Tekst" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="White" Height="1020" Width="1673"/>
</Grid>
```

**Code main window:**

```
   public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    string hint = "";
    string verwijder = "";

    Window1 win1 = new Window1();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        win1.Show();
    }

    private void Verstuur_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        hint = Textbox.Text;
        Window1 win1 = new Window1(hint);
        win1.Show();
    }

    private void Verwijder_Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Textbox.Text = verwijder;
        Window1 win1 = new Window1(verwijder);
        win1.Show();
    }
}
```

**Code second window:**

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public Window1(string hint) : this()
    {
        lbl_Tekst.Content = hint;
    }
}
```

Hope you could help to get it to refresh instead of a new popupscreen.

Comment: if you are new to WPF, start with reading up on MVVM pattern, choose one of the MVVM frameworks to learn and only then play with multiple windows - they are a bit tricky

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a method on `Window1` class to update the label.
Like:

```
public void UpdateLabel(string text)
{
    lbl_Tekst.Content = text;
}
```

You would then call it from your `MainWindow` like this:

```
win1.UpdateLabel("I am updated content");
```

You should then have the content of that Label updated. However I would advise you read up on MvvM and `DataContexts` it would make it a lot easier for you to manipulate contents of UI elements without actually referencing these elements.